# Where is stored the total number of crafted electronic circuits for the "Mass Production 3" achievement?

Tags: factorio

I have a steam installation of Factorio 0.16 and an experimental version 0.17 in a folder somewhere else with a bunch of new saves to test the new features.

I'd like to do the "Mass production 3" achievement on steam and if I get this right, this achievement is save-independant. Once the 0.17 gets stable and downloaded via steam, I'll merge the 0.17 new worlds I tried with my current steam installation.

**Question : when the saves will be incorporated in my steam installation, will the total electronic circuits add up to the score?**

And more general, **where is the green circuit counter stored?**

Quick edit: I tested the update of the green circuit counter during a session, the steam achievement counter is updated after the game exists. The ingame counter is not precise enough (rounds to first decimal in engineer notation)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you only play 0.17 now, you could also switch to the experimental branch in Steam now instead of later.

Comment: @Tim I prefer to wait for stability on steam to avoid managing/rollbacking saves automatically uploaded to the cloud in case of a bad update... I know devs produce reliable code even in experimental ([ahem](https://forums.factorio.com/65075)) but I prefer leaving steam stable